# Convert hourly data values to 15minute data values and vice versa

Tags: excel, vba, data-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem: I have a time series A that contains hourly data. There are a total of 8760 data points in the time series A.

```
01.01.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 01:00:00
01.01.2023 02:00:00
....
31.12.2023 21:00:00
31.12.2023 22:00:00
31.12.2023 23:00:00
```

The data of time series A must be converted to quarter hour format, this would result in time series B, for example.

```
01.01.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 00:15:00
01.01.2023 00:30:00
01.01.2023 00:45:00
01.01.2023 01:00:00
01.01.2023 01:15:00
01.01.2023 01:30:00
01.01.2023 01:45:00
....
31.12.2023 23:00:00
31.12.2023 23:15:00
31.12.2023 23:30:00
31.12.2023 23:45:00
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
Sub hTo15MinutesV2()
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim Minute_currentDate As Date
    Dim LngRowMax As Double
    Dim LngFirstRow As Double
    Dim startPoint As Range
    Dim Input_ As Range
    Dim Output_ As Range
    Dim i_Input
    Dim j_Output
    Dim Last_i_Input
    Dim Last_j_Output As Integer
    
    'Set ranges for the input and the output
    Set Input_ = Range("A1:A8760")
    Set Output_ = Range("B1:B35040")

    Last_i_Input = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Last_j_Output = Last_i_Input * 4
                     
    'Set the staring point
    Set startPoint = Sheet2.Range("A:A")
    
    'find the last filled cell
    LngRowMax = Sheet2.Cells(startPoint.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'find the first filled cell
    LngFirstRow = LngRowMax - (LngRowMax - 1)
    
    'The start and end dates in the input area are set
    startDate = Sheet2.Cells(LngFirstRow, 1) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)
    endDate = Sheet2.Cells(LngRowMax, 1) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)

    currentDate = startDate
    
    Minute_currentDate = currentDate
    For j_Output = 1 To Last_j_Output
        For i_Input = 1 To Last_i_Input
            For Minute_currentDate = 0 To 45 Step 15
                Output_.Cells(j_Output, 1).Value = currentDate
                j_Output = j_Output + 1
                currentDate = currentDate + TimeSerial(0, Minute_currentDate, 0)
            Next Minute_currentDate
        Next i_Input
    Next j_Output
    
End Sub
```

This is the result I get, it is obviously wrong:

```
01.01.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 00:15:00
01.01.2023 00:45:00
01.01.2023 01:30:00
01.01.2023 01:30:00
01.01.2023 01:45:00
```

and so on

This is what I would expect:

```
01.01.2023 00:00:00
01.01.2023 00:15:00
01.01.2023 00:30:00
01.01.2023 00:45:00
01.01.2023 01:00:00
01.01.2023 01:15:00
01.01.2023 01:30:00
01.01.2023 01:45:00
01.01.2023 02:00:00
...
31.12.2023 23:00:00
31.12.2023 23:15:00
31.12.2023 23:30:00
31.12.2023 23:45:00
```

Thanks for your help I appreciate it very much.

Comment: To go from your 15 min series to an hourly series, in Excel 2021 or later, you can use a worksheet formula `=LET(start,MIN($A:$A),end,MAX($A:$A),SEQUENCE((end-start+TIME(0,15,0))*24,,start,TIME(1,0,0)))`.  No need for VBA. You can use a similar formula for the reverse.

Comment: Title and body does not align. Which is the pre and post time series format?

Comment: I think it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve ... you can also use a filter (using the Excel UI) to filter on 'ends with' "00:00" if all you want is to leave the relevant rows visible ... please clarify your question

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
First of all, the problem can't be solved with Excel formulas because it's a very long time series and Excel does a lot of calculations and consumes a lot of computing power.
Secondly, I have revised the code and written down the explanation a bit more clearly, I hope this helps to understand it better.

Comment: Does your source have the **entire** hourly series from start to finish?

Comment: Following @Ron Rosefield's comment, the transition from an hourly series to a 15 minutes would be 
`=LET(start,MIN($F:$F),end,MAX($F:$F),SEQUENCE((end-start+TIME(1,0,0))*96,,start,TIME(0,15,0)))`

Comment: The source is from the beginning to the end in hourly granularity.

Comment: I think my loop is not correct, but I just can't figure out what is wrong with it. When running the loop, the first hour (00:00:00) is correctly split into four 15-minute intervals. From hour two (01:00:00) the splitting into 15-minute intervals doesn't work anymore then it goes straight to 01:30:00 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

Set the parameters of `last_j_output` and `currentdate` according to the requirements.

The `If` statement is required because of a rounding problem of Excel.

```
Sub datefill()

last_j_output = DateSerial(2024, 1, 1)
currentdate = DateSerial(2023, 1, 1)
Columns("A").Clear
Columns("A").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Set targetrange = Range("A1")
Do While DateValue(currentdate) < last_j_output
    If Abs(Round(currentdate) - currentdate) < 0.00001158 Then currentdate = Round(currentdate)
    targetrange.Value = currentdate
    Set targetrange = targetrange.Offset(1)
    currentdate = DateAdd("n", 15, currentdate)
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your innermost loop you are successively increasing `currentDate` by
0 minutes (first pass through loop)
15 minutes (second pass through loop)
30 minutes (third pass though loop)
45 minutes (fourth pass through loop)

As a result if `currentDate` is, say, `01/01/2023 00:00:00` as it enters the loop it will have the following values at the end of each of the 4 passes through the loop:

`01/01/2023 00:00:00` (end of first pass, ie unchanged because 0 mins added)
`01/01/2023 00:15:00` (end of second pass, 15 mins added)
`01/01/2023 00:45:00` (end of third pass, 30 mins added)
`01/01/2023 00:01:30` (end of fourth pass, 45 mins added)

To correct this, simply execute your inner loop 4 times (as you currently do) but just add 15 mins to `currentDate` on each pass.

A second (but less critical) issue is you have too many loops. The outermost loop uses `j_Output` as the `For...Next` counter BUT the innermost loop contains updates this counter through the statement

`j_Output = j_Output + 1`

On each pass through the outermost loop this statement gets executed `4*i_Last_Input` times because of the two inner loops. As a result, `j_Output` has the value of `1 + 4*i_Last_Input` at the end of its first pass through this loop and, in consequence, the outer loop only ever gets one pass through it. It is, effectively, redundant and adds nothing from its presence. It can (and should) be removed.

If each pass through the inner loop adds 15 minutes then the initial value of `currentDate` needs adjusting to get the correct initial output value back to `startDate`.

The following should correct your code (note `Minute_currentDate` no longer used but a new variable `i_Quarter` has been added)

```
currentDate = startDate - TimeSerial(0,15,0)  'CHANGED
   
For i_Input = 1 To Last_i_Input
    For i_Quarter = 1 To 4
                
         j_Output = j_Output + 1
         currentDate = currentDate + TimeSerial(0,15,0)  'CHANGED
         Output_.Cells(j_Output, 1).Value = currentDate
         'currentDate now written to Output_ after being updated

    Next i_Quarter
Next i_Input
```